# Excel VBA to SQL Server 2016 Connection String Error

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, adodb

We´re trying to get VBA access to our native server database with the plugin ADODB in Excel. However, we´re running into the same error message no matter what connection string configuration we´re trying.

Any help would be appreciated! See below image and code.

```
Sub test()

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    ConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=databaseb006;Database=EIU"
    Conn.Open

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please check that SQLOLEDB drive is install on the Client machine?

Comment: Just upgraded to latest version - problem still exists!

Comment: which version ? Please cross reference your connection string with this website https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/.

Comment: What does cross referencing a connection string mean exactly?

Comment: depending on the driver version connection string can changes. so make sure that your connection string is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Consider first checking if `SQLOLEDB` is among installed OLEDB providers with below PowerShell script, borrowed from this [@josepmv's blog](http://dbadailystuff.com/list-all-ole-db-providers-in-powershell) page, also available on his [Gitub repo](https://github.com/josepmv/dbadailystuff/blob/master/list_all_OLEDB_Provider.ps1).

**PowerShell** *(run .ps1 script inside Powershell ISE for x86 (32-bit) and non-x86 (64-bit))*

```bsh
function Get-OledbRegistered
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]])]
    param ()

    Process
    {
        $list = New-Object ([System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]])

        foreach ($provider in [System.Data.OleDb.OleDbEnumerator]::GetRootEnumerator())
        {
            $v = New-Object PSObject        
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $provider.FieldCount; $i++) 
            {
                Add-Member -in $v NoteProperty $provider.GetName($i) $provider.GetValue($i)
            }
            $list.Add($v)
        }
        return $list
    }
}

$list = Get-OledbRegistered
$list | ?{ $_.SOURCES_NAME.IndexOf('SQL') -ge 0 }
```

Script above searches for any source name containing `SQL`. Simply, run `list` at end to show all OLEDB providers. Also, the available provider must match the bit-version of your MS Office. For example, MS Office 32-bit version may not be able to run OLEDB 64-bit providers and vice versa. Similarly your SQL Server bit-version must align as well to the provider.

Also, do note you can download the [latest OLEDB driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016) which raises an important message (emphasis added):

> The previous Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (SQLOLEDB) and SQL Server Native Client OLE DB provider (SQLNCLI) **remains deprecated and it is not recommended to use** either for new development work.
>   
> ...
>   The new OLE DB provider is called the Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (MSOLEDBSQL). The new provider will be updated with the most recent server features going forward.

---

From there, adjust connection strings as needed according to availability on machine. Below are typical, untested examples for illustration.

**VBA**

```vb
Sub test()

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    ConnString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=myServer\myInstance;Database=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    Conn.Open

    ConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=myServer\myInstance;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Conn.Open

    ConnString = "Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=myServer\myInstance;Database=myDatabase;UID=myUser;PWD=mypwd"
    Conn.Open

End Sub
```