# Improve SQL query in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have 3 tables in the Excel workbook that I access with SQL.
There is Inscriptions table that holds the `AGENT_ID` and `MLS_ID`, `PHOTOS` table that holds all the photos that came in recent feed for `MLS_ID`, and `PHOTOS_CURRENT` that holds all the photos that are currently in the system for `MLS_ID`.
The goal is to find if there are photos in the new feed that are not in the system currently.

I tried to query using `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` approach. Both take too long to run (sometimes 2 minutes per `AGENT_ID`).

`NOT EXISTS` approach:

```vb
sqlQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT INSCR.MLS_ID FROM [INSCRIPTIONS_CURRENT$] INSCR, [PHOTOS$] P1 " & _
                "WHERE INSCR.AGENT_ID = " & inpAgentId & _
                " AND INSCR.MLS_ID = P1.MLS_ID AND NOT exists (select 1 from [PHOTOS_CURRENT$] PC1 where PC1.MLS_ID = P1.MLS_ID and PC1.PHOTO_ID = P1.PHOTO_ID)"
```

`NOT IN` approach:

```vb
sqlQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT INSCR.MLS_ID FROM [INSCRIPTIONS_CURRENT$] INSCR, [PHOTOS$] P1 " & _
                "WHERE INSCR.AGENT_ID = " & inpAgentId & _
                " AND INSCR.MLS_ID = P1.MLS_ID AND INSCR.MLS_ID NOT IN (select MLS_ID from [PHOTOS_CURRENT$] PC1 where PC1.MLS_ID = P1.MLS_ID and PC1.PHOTO_ID = P1.PHOTO_ID)"
```

DB connection is done as follows:

```vb
Sub Connect()

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.CommandTimeout = 120

End Sub
```

The query is sent to the procedure for processing as follows:

```vb
Function select_query(sqlQuery As String) As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1

    Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    objRecordset.Open sqlQuery, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, 
    adCmdText

    Set select_query = objRecordset

End Function
```

Any suggestions to improve the performance?

Comment: How large are the tables?

Comment: @TimWilliams Around 20,000 records in PHOTOS and PHOTOS_CURRENT, around 2,000 in INSCRIPTIONS

Comment: Please provide a fuller code block not line snippets so we can see whole process. Otherwise, remember [excel is not a database](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+is+not+a+database), so use an actual one like its sibling `ms access`, that can index on fields for faster table scans!

Comment: @Parfait there is no much sense to add anything else to what I already provided. If any records found by the query they are inserted into the output array and sent back to the calling routine. I know Excel is not a real database, I work in the constraints that the company imposes on me. This Excel has about 20 worksheets and is used as a database, take it or leave it. I did my proposal for improvement to the company, but while they make a correct decision I have to make this piece of code work.

Comment: Understood re the database, but can we see if you are running ADO or DAO, OLEDB provider or ODBC driver? Looping through a recordset or exporting with `CopyFromRecordset`?

Comment: Please edit your post with code lines not in hard-to-read comments. It would help to see how `objConnection` is assigned. Please note the Stackoverflow rules of [MCVE].

Comment: I will loop through the recordset to fill in the output array.
That is definitely not the problem. Right now I have the PHOTOS and PHOTOS_CURRENT table that have exactly same information. The performance issue lies in the query.

Comment: @Parfait I edited the post.

Comment: If you're running this in a loop it seems like you could create a table out of your `NOT EXISTS` query and join on it instead of repeating that query for every agent.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following tips that may help:

- **Explicit JOIN**: Right now you are running the outdated implicit join with a match of IDs in the `WHERE` clause and not the current standard of the explicit `JOIN` clause. In most database engines, this should not change performance but anecdotal evidence suggests on specific use cases it can:

  ```sql
  SELECT DISTINCT INSCR.MLS_ID 
  FROM [INSCRIPTIONS_CURRENT$] INSCR
  INNER JOIN [PHOTOS$] P1 ON INSCR.MLS_ID = P1.MLS_ID 
  WHERE INSCR.AGENT_ID = " & inpAgentId & _
    AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from [PHOTOS_CURRENT$] PC1  
                    where PC1.MLS_ID = P1.MLS_ID and PC1.PHOTO_ID = P1.PHOTO_ID)
  ```
- **GROUP BY vs DISTINCT**: This is a regular debate in SQL where different database engines process the non-duplicates queries differently. In theory, there should be no difference in performance but anecdotal evidence suggest otherwise. Therefore, consider an equivalent `GROUP BY` version:

  ```sql
  SELECT INSCR.MLS_ID 
  FROM [INSCRIPTIONS_CURRENT$] INSCR
  INNER JOIN [PHOTOS$] P1 ON INSCR.MLS_ID = P1.MLS_ID 
  WHERE INSCR.AGENT_ID = " & inpAgentId & _
    AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from [PHOTOS_CURRENT$] PC1  
                    where PC1.MLS_ID = P1.MLS_ID and PC1.PHOTO_ID = P1.PHOTO_ID)
  GROUP BY INSCR.MLS_ID
  ```
- **DAO Connection**: Since querying workbooks utilizes the JET/ACE SQL Engine, consider DAO as a specific interface that can exploit many advantages of this engine and not ADO a more generalized interface across any data source (Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, etc.).

  ```vb
  ' ADD REFERENCE: Microsoft Office #.# Access Database Engine Object Library
  Dim conn As New DAO.DBEngine, db As DAO.Database, qdef As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset

  Set db = conn.OpenDatabase("C:\Path\To\Workbook.xls", False, True, "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;")
  Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sqlQuery)

  ...    

  rst.Close: db.Close
  Set rst = Nothing: Set db = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
  ```
- **OLEDB (ACE) Connection**: Consider the newer OLEDB provider which should still work with any version of Excel (.xls or .xlsx, .xlsb, .xlsm). Check available providers with this [PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57167973/1422451).

  ```vb
  objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" ...

  objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;" ...
  ```
- **ODBC Connection**: Connecting interfaces can pose different performance of query execution where anecdotal evidence differs from theory. Therefore, consider replacing the OLEDB provider for ODBC driver connection:

  ```vb
  ' DRIVER VERSION
  objConnection.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
                         & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Excel.xls;"

  ' DSN VERSION
  objConnection.Open "DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=C:\Path\To\Excel.xls;"
  ```
- **Cursor/Lock Types**: Experiment with the [cursor types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cursortypeenum?view=sql-server-2017) as performance can vary such as `adOpenForwardOnly`vs `adOpenStatic` and even [LockType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/locktypeenum?view=sql-server-2017) with `adLockOptimistic` vs `adLockReadOnly`.

Comment: Thank you @Parfait. Your suggestion would help if I had power to change the whole system. Unfortunately, as I said, I am bound to the existing Connect-Select-Disconnect approach which is used by hundreds of queries in this Excel database. The full regression testing is out of question. I'd rather wait for them to approve the move to a real DB and make it work there.

Comment: I do not undestand your comment. All of these solutions can be handled in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TimWilliams, your comment was most helpful in solving this problem.
What I ended up doing is writing a separate routine that, during feed load,  creates a table of all photos that were changed like this:

```
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO [PHOTO_UPDATES$] SELECT P1.* " & _
                "FROM [PHOTOS$] P1 LEFT JOIN [PHOTOS_CURRENT$] PC1 " & _
                "ON P1.MLS_ID = PC1.MLS_ID AND P1.PHOTO_ID = PC1.PHOTO_ID WHERE PC1.PHOTO_ID is NULL"
```

Then, when creating the worklist per agent, the following is done:

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT INSCR.MLS_ID " & _
                "FROM [PHOTO_UPDATES$] PU1 , [INSCRIPTIONS_CURRENT$] INSCR " & _
                "WHERE INSCR.AGENT_ID = " & inpAgentId & " " & _
                "AND PU1.MLS_ID = INSCR.MLS_ID "
```

Both routines take less than 1 second to run.