# Combine csv files within SQL and then update to existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 csv files, which I will call table1 and table2

table1

```
Name   Location
Jim    NY
```

table2

```
Name  Location
Rick  CA
```

I would like to **combine** these **vertically**:

Desired output:

table3

```
Name   Location
Jim    NY
Rick   CA
```

Once **combined** vertically as table 3, I would like to now combine table3 to my existing table within SQL server (table4)

table4 (already existing within SQL Server)

```
Name    Location
Lisa    TX
```

Final output

```
Name    Location
Lisa    TX
Jim     NY
Rick    CA
```

This is what I have done:

I realize that I can add the values into existing tables (from a csv file) using the BULK INSERT statement:

```
 BULK INSERT test
 FROM 'C:\Test\test1.csv'
 WITH
   (
     FIRSTROW = 2,
     rowterminator='\n',
     fieldterminator=','
   )
```

I am not sure how to initially combine table1 and table2 within SQL, and then add this data to table4

Any insight is appreciated

Comment: I would import all csv-s into separate tables and then use simple SQL to insert records into your old table - makes easy to check for duplicates and do other validation.

Comment: Are this large files?  You could do it in a transaction and forget about table3, just insert into table4 twice.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869/is-sql-server-bulk-insert-transactional)

Comment: @SteveC Yes they are pretty large. Ill check the documentation you provided. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.  If the files are very large then its logging could be very large as well.

```
set xact_abort on;

begin transaction
begin try

    bulk insert table4
    from 'C:\Test\test1.csv'
     WITH  (
         FIRSTROW = 2,
         rowterminator='\n',
         fieldterminator=',',
         tablock);

    bulk insert table4
    from 'C:\Test\test2.csv'
     WITH  (
         FIRSTROW = 2,
         rowterminator='\n',
         fieldterminator=',',
         tablock)

    commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    rollback transaction
end catch
```

Comment: Ok let me try this. How would I assure there are no dupes? (Is there a way to assure that)

Comment: The table could be set to ignore duplicates on insert by by setting IGNORE_DUP_KEY index option in your index or unique constraint definition

Comment: Thank you I will try this. Could this be saved as a stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, just prefix it with CREATE PROC and assign a name and parameters

Answer (score 2):

Consider also [`OPENROWSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [`OPENDATASOURCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/opendatasource-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (assuming user has permission) to query CSVs like a table and integrate into an insert-select query. This would only work for SQL Server on Windows machines.

```sql
INSERT INTO table4 ([Name], [Location], ...)
SELECT t.[Name], t.[Location], ...
FROM OPENROWSET
   (  'MSDASQL'
     ,'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}'
     ,'select * from C:\Path\To\table1.csv'
   ) AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM table4
   WHERE table4.[Name] = t.[Name]
     AND table4.[Location] = t.[Location])
```

You can even use the MS Access engine OLEDB provider which can query Excel workbooks, Access database tables, and text files. Do note below points database to folder of CSV and treats the CSV files as table. Also, provider can vary: `12.0`, `15.0`, even `16.0`.

```sql
INSERT INTO table4 ([Name], [Location], ...)
SELECT t.[Name], t.[Location], ...
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                    'Text;Database=C:\Path\To\CSV;HDR=YES')..[table2#csv] AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM table4
   WHERE table4.[Name] = t.[Name]
     AND table4.[Location] = t.[Location])
```

You can check available [OLEDB drivers with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57167973/1422451) including `MSDASQL` and `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.##.0`. (remove `.IndexOf('SQL')` on last line for all listings).